# Error: Unknown arguments: cap, copy, android;, npx, cap, open, android

Tags: angular, capacitor

Trying to execute the command `ng build -c=mobile; npx cap copy android; npx cap open android` and getting the following error

> `Error: Unknown arguments: cap, copy, android;, npx, cap, open, android`

I have installed `@capacitor/cli` globally but still facing this issue. Also restarted the pc as well after installing this package.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Capacitor documentation below: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started

You need to install capacitor core alongside the CLI:

```
npm i @capacitor/core
npm i -D @capacitor/cli
```

And also initialize Capacitor as follows:

```
npx cap init
```

Comment: `@capacitor/core` is already installed. Also the `@capacitor/cli` as depency.

Comment: Try running the commands separately: 1) ng build -c=mobile 2) npx cap sync 3) npx cap copy 4) npx cap open android - note the addition of npx cap sync (after building)